# How to include all files of a git repo in a parent repo?

Tags: git, github

I have large project in a git repo and I've open source certain parts of it. The open sourced parts have their own git repos in separate folders within the parent repo. However, as soon as I initialized a repo in one of the inner directories, those files are no longer added and tracked by the parent git repo.

I dont like this because the parent repo wont work if the child repos are on the wrong commit. This is a big problem if you want to go back in history. So I want to be able to track all files, including the files in the sub-repos in the parent repo. It seems easy enough. I dont want to use submodules or subtrees or anythign fancy. Simply duplicating the code between the two repos is fine by me.

---

Edit:

```
/proj1/.git
/proj1/src/main.js
/proj1/packages/subproj1/.git
/proj1/packages/subproj1/helper.js
```

When I'm in `/proj`, I want `git add .` to add both `/proj1/src/main.js` and `/proj1/packages/subproj1/helper.js` to `/proj1/.git`.

When I'm in `/proj1/packages/subproj1`, I want `git add .` to add both only `/proj1/packages/subproj1/helper.js` to `/proj1/packages/subproj1/.git`.

Comment: It sounds to me like submodules might be the way to go, although your question is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want files to be tracked by both repos. I made an edit with a direct example

Comment: Could you instead use one repository with multiple branches?  My gut feeling is that you are barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: its not about branching. its just shared code. I want to open source only part of my project, which is contained in a different repo.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "repo" which is used to manage multiple git projects. repo is an open source project.
[Repo project details](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html)